# Problem related to solving a system of functionals

Tags: equation-solving, functions

Can anyone please help me to solve this system with Mathematica? I don't know which command to use ... Thank you very much!

I know it can be done by hand, but I would like to know how to do it with Mathematica.

[image: equation]

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Solve`, from next time it would be better for you if you take help from the documentation, before you put your question on **Mathematica StackExchange**

```
Solve[{v1 == -1 + v2  x + (1 - x) v1, v2 == -1 + v1  x + (1 - x) v3, 
  v3 == -1 + (1 - x) v2}, {v1, v2, v3}]
```

which gives the answer:

```
{{v1 -> -((2 (-2 + x))/((-1 + x) x)), v2 -> -((-3 + x)/((-1 + x) x)), 
  v3 -> -(3/x)}}
```